# Set id attribute in Symfony Form to twig variable

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I want to add a twig variable to my table row id in a form.

```
{% for child in form %}               
    {{ form_widget(child, {'id':'asterisks-rating-loop.index' }) }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Currently it is not being parsed as a twig variable. Is there any way to set the id to 'asterisks-rating-'loop.index using this setup without the use of Javascript or jQuery?

I tried 'escaping' it with:

```
{{ form_widget(child, {'id':'asterisks-rating-{{loop.index}}' }) }}
{{ form_widget(child, {'id':'asterisks-rating-'{{loop.index}}'' }) }}
```

But obviously none of these solutions work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
{{ form_widget(child, {'id':'asterisks-rating-' ~ loop.index }) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice should be:

- to add a [form collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) instead of several forms if you can (eg. if your forms are not processed individually).
- to add your dynamic id in the type's `getName()` method if your forms are processed individually, example:

<kbd>BobType.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class BobType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $suffix;

    public function __construct($suffix)
    {
        $this->suffix = $suffix;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
           ->add('whatever', 'text')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array (
                'data_class' => 'Fuz\AppBundle\Entity\BobData',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'BobType-' . $suffix;
    }

}
```

<kbd>BobController.php</kbd>

```
$formA = new BobType("hello"); // {{ formA.whatever.vars.id == BobType-hello-whatever }}
$formB = new BobType("world"); // {{ formB.whatever.vars.id == BobType-world-whatever }}
```